# NODE JS & MySQL Foreign Key Multilevel JSON Object

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

I'm using NODEJS and MySQL for an API server and I ran into an issue. The queries that I'm running have multiple rows of results due to foreign keys.

```
User Table           Address Table
|id|  name|         |id|user_id|                        Address|
| 1| frank|         | 1|      1|       123 main street, Moncton|
| 2| steve|         | 2|      2|97 duplessie street, Edmundston|
                    | 3|      2|    933 manhole av, Grand Sault|
```

How would I go about to get a multilevel json object like below for my query result, or at least, for my API response.

```
{
  "id":1,
  "name": "frank",
  "addresses": [
    {"id":1,"Address":"123 main street, Moncton"}
  ]
},
{
  "id":2,
  "name": "steve",
  "addresses": [
    {"id":2,"Address":"97 duplessie street, Edmundston"},
    {"id":3,"Address":"933 manhole av, Grand Sault"}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed @dmfay direction and came up with a solution that works for me.

This a function where I pass the 2 JSON objects to merge addresses into users JSON and returns everything in a single JSON object.

```
function combineResults(users, addresses){
  ***********************************
  *** Go through each user object ***
  ***********************************
  users.forEach(function(user) {
      user.addresses = addresses.find(address => address.user_id === user.id);
  }

  return users;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just running raw queries, the results you get are the results you get. Object-relational mapping libraries like Objection, Bookshelf, or Sequelize will handle this for you automatically but may involve more setup and/or abstraction than you'd like.

If you'd rather keep it minimal, you can always process the result array yourself. I ran into this exact issue some time ago with my own project (a data mapper for Postgres) and developed a [decomposer](https://gitlab.com/dmfay/massive-js/blob/master/lib/util/decompose.js) you should be able to cannibalize without issues. See the [docs](https://massivejs.org/docs/resultset-decomposition) for constructing schemas.

Comment: Please update your links and flag for a moderator to undelete.